# How could I reach a data property with .validate rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I trying to verify if an user profile has an specific property in order to allow `.write` data in a path of my Firebase, but I haven't found the way.

This is the user profiles structure in my Firebase:

```
root
|--user_profiles
|   |--uid
|   |  |--name
|   |  |--email
|   |  |--invite // How could I reach the properties of this path with my .validate rules?
```

And these are the rules I'm trying to make it work:

```
 "invitations": {
      ".write": true,
      ".validate": "auth.provider == 'provider' && auth.id == '123456'",
      "$invitation": {
        ".read": true, 
        "used": {
          ".validate": "root.child('user_profiles').hasChild(auth.uid).(...)" // I'm stuck here.
        }
      }  
    }
```

The idea is to allow `.write` in "used" if, and only if, the property "invite" match with my requirements (Whether they are equal or not, for example).

I'm really stuck in this and I don't want to make it works without understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply concatenate the paths to the invite:

```
".validate": "root.child('user_profiles/'+auth.uid+'/invite').val() === ???"
```

Replacing `???` with your criterium, such as data.val() (for the current value at this path), or newData.val() (for the value being set at this path).

Comment: I tried it but I received this error in the simulator: `Type Error: + only operates on numbers and strings.` What could be wrong?

Comment: Never mind, the error is just happening in the simulator; `.validate` rule is working like a charm!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. The issue in simulator would be because you haven't entered an object (e.g. `{ uid: 'kato' }`) in the "custom auth" field or forgot to press the Authenticate button. Cheers.